# How do I configure an nginx proxy_pass for a url with special characters

Tags: nginx

My configuration uses a proxy path for a url prefixed by `v0.1`. Nginx doesn't proxy for my backend. When I change to just `v` everything works as it should. My suspicion is that the `.` has special meaning.

How should I modify this configuration for it to work?

```
 location /v0.1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
 }
```

Comment: maybe this belongs on serverfault…

Comment: I think you can use regex for that. Check `optional_modifier location_match` here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: Do you want the `v0.1` passed to the proxy or stripped off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your configuration is supposed to do. But I have tested two similar scenarios which both work as expected.

The first will delete the leading `/v0.1` from the URI before sending it upstream, so the service on 8080 never sees the `/v0.1` part:

```
location /v0.1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

The second will pass the entire URI (including the `/v0.1` prefix) to the upstream:

```
location /v0.1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: so weird… I must be going crazy. It works as advertised now.